# Display multi-select lookup using XSLT List View webpart

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a list with two lookup columns. Each allow multiple selections. I will say right of the bat that I am limited by admins to only using the XSLT List View web part. The DataView Web part not available on the site.

The lookup column displays results as "one;two;three..." All on one line and without a space after the semi-colon. I found a solution online using the DataView web part but I cannot get it to work on the XSLT List View web part. https://deannaschneider.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/displaying-multiple-select-fields-one-per-row-in-a-dataview-web-part/

Anyone know who to get this working on the XSLT List View web part?

Comment: This is for SP2010? At what point are you experiencing problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and I solved it.

I hava a multi value Lookup Field named "g_x00fc_ltig_x0020_in_x0020__x0028_lang", where I want to display each selection in a new line instead of the default ";" separators.

You must substitute my field name by your field name.

I went into SharePoint Designer 2010 and opened my .aspx view.
In the code I searched for the "xsl:template" tag (last line in my code snippet) and copied the following code just in front of the searched tag:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
<xsl:param name="text" />
<xsl:param name="replace" />
<xsl:param name="by" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_printTableCell_EcbAllowed.g_x00fc_ltig_x0020_in_x0020__x0028_lang_x0029_" match="FieldRef[@Name='g_x00fc_ltig_x0020_in_x0020__x0028_lang_x0029_']" mode="printTableCellEcbAllowed" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="class" />
<td>
    <xsl:if test="@ClassInfo='Menu' or @ListItemMenu='TRUE'">
        <xsl:attribute name="height">100%</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="onmouseover">OnChildItem(this)</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:call-template name="getTDClassValue">
            <xsl:with-param name="class" select="$class" />
            <xsl:with-param name="Type" select="@Type"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="ClassInfo" select="@ClassInfo"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:attribute>


    <xsl:variable name="thisRow">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="';'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'&lt;br /&gt;'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$thisRow" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</td>
</xsl:template>
```

The first template in the code is the given string-replace function from your reference.

The second template I have generated by formatting my column with a background color in SharePoint Designer and removed the "style" and "color" from the  tag and additinally some other not needed code lines.

I added the code between and including the lines containing "thisRow".

Save it, and voila – it works.

Kind regards
Ernst

Comment: I was missing the '&lt; and &gt;' around the br. Was using different coding to replace the < and >. Thanks!